# Same function doesn't work on different platform in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm using React JS library to track user scrolling height and apply function according to the data received.

It's working fine at [Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-robinson-rv3ro?file=/src/scroll.js), but once I run it on npm localhost it's failing to exist although I'm using the exact same code.

This is the function I'm trying to apply on localhost but allways returns 0:

```
//Scroll event listener to change menu background color
const ScrollingElement = () => {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);

  function logit() {
    setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function watchScroll() {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", logit);
    }
    watchScroll();
    // Remove listener (like componentWillUnmount)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", logit);
    };
  }, []);
  console.log(scrollY);
  return scrollY;
}
```

I have tried to debug the `scrollY` variable, on localhost I receive allways value of 0, no matter what.
My guess it's some sort of definition error, that codesandbox.io have and I don't.

Also tried the following debugging on App function and also returns 0:

```
function App() {
  console.log(ScrollingElement());
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu scrollHeight={ScrollingElement()}></Menu>
      <Home></Home>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I run my code on localhost that works in codesandbox?

Comment: @evolutionxbox but how to return it properly? I can't really see the syntax of how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried it in your codepen, and the code works as expected. May you make sure the code in the question is a [mcve] so we can help you debug the issue.

Comment: @evolutionxbox try running it on localhost, It's not working. I will share some debugging I have made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<ScrollingElement />` is working, but you need to make sure that you parent component is actually scrollable. The simplest solution is to create new `<Wrapper />` component and set its height using css.

```
function Wrapper() {
  return (
    <div style={{height: "200vh"}}>
      <ScrollingElement />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Runnable example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Wrapper() {
  return (
    <div style={{height: "200vh", backgroundColor: "beige"}}>
      <ScrollingElement />
    </div>
  );
}

const ScrollingElement = () => {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);

  function logit() {
    setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function watchScroll() {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", logit);
    }
    watchScroll();

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", logit);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(scrollY);
  return scrollY;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: https://www.yotamdahan.com/portfolio/ I have tried what you have mentioned, just wont work.. something seems to divide the page, if you try to scroll on the menu part you just wont be able to do so..

Comment: No, so I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559492/how-to-change-the-background-color-when-scrolling but I have tried your solution

Comment: If you run the snippet above using "Run code snippet" button and it's not working then try to run this in different browser. Let me know if this still not working.

Comment: It does working for me in the snippets, but once I run it in my website it's not working.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220045/react-conversation

Comment: In this case, please update the question with exact code you use on your website.