# React divides page and blocking scroll event listener

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm not sure why, but [my page](https://www.yotamdahan.com/portfolio/) is been divided by React.js library, if you try to scroll down when your mouse is hovering top navigation menu, you wont be able to do so.

But if you scroll down on any other part of the screen you will be scrolling perfectly fine.

Now I have been trying to use event listener, that on scroll will change the menu background, following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559492/how-to-change-the-background-color-when-scrolling) and it just wont work, because react has divided my page to 2 parts, one part is the menu, the other is the rest of the page.

Menu.js

```
import React from "react";
import './css/menu.css';
import logo from './images/logo.png'

export default class Menu extends React.Component{
    state ={className:"" };
    componentDidMount(){
      window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
      console.log(this.state.className);
    }
    
    handleScroll=()=>{
      if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
          if(!this.state.className){
            this.setState({ className: "blue" });   
            console.log('added');
          }
      }else{
          if(this.state.className){
            this.setState({ className: "" });
            console.log('removed');
          }
      }
     
    }
    render(){
      return(
        <header id="navbar" className={this.state.className}>
            <nav role="navigation">
                <div className="logo">
                    <img src={logo} alt="Triple V logo - עיצוב ופיתוח אתרים" />
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">דף הבית</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">קצת עלינו</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">השירותים שלנו</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">תיק עבודות</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">מגזין מקצועי</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">צור קשר</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
      );
    }
  }
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Home from './pages/home/home.js';
import Menu from './menu.js';
import './App.css';
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu/>
      <Home/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

How can I prevent this divide and enable full page scrolling that will ensure event scroll listener to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu is apparently positioned with z-index higher than the rest of the page, so changing the z-index to 0 on the header should fix the issue.

Comment: It does changes a little bit the scrolling on hovering, but the event listener still not working. I have debugged the code, the `blue` class doesn't adds up because the scroll listener doesn't activated (Used `console.log` to check that).